# Answer tab on Activity -> Summary tab is empty

Tags: support, bug, answers

May you please help me: this started to reproduce today, both on desktop and mobile site versions. I cannot see anything but scoring in Answer tab in Activity -> Summary, however, answers are seen in Profile. Also in Answers tab I cannot see question titles.

This happens not only on my user, but on any other user Activity tab.

Notes: cleared cache, tried in incognito mode and in different browsers. Console has no errors, same as network.

[image: Activity -> Summary]
[image: Activity -> Answers]
[image: Profile]

Comment: "Me, too!" I have no insight, but from observation it seems that SE has been making a number of modifications to the dashboards - especially the 'Activity' tab.  Hopefully it will be noticed and fixed soon. Should you put a `[support]` tag on this question? If I understand correctly, that should notify the folks "upstairs".

Comment: Have added, thank you!

Comment: My Answers are back.

Comment: Yep, works now for me, too, thank you for an update)